# Right balance between English seach and Japanese search in Solr

Tags: solr

I'm using Solr for some time. It's working fine with English language. Now files with japanese also included. Here the major problem arises.

When I'm searching for Japanese its giving inappropriate results. I tried to use kurumoji but I don't how to configure this. I am unable to find a solution for both Japanese and English both at same time.

Comment: Do you know if the content is in english or japanese before indexing?

Comment: Hard to say. Could you share your schema.xml?

Comment: @MatsLindh No i don't know before .It contain mixture of these files
Is it possible if we know before giving for indexing???

Answer (score 1):

As you do not know the language before indexing, you probably want to look into using [Solr's Language Detection](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/LanguageDetection) in an update processor. This will attempt to detect which language the content is in, and then index the content to fields postfixed with the language code (see `langid.map`). That way you can have separate analyze and filter sequences for each language, using japanese language features for the field which receives the japanese content, and english content features (stemming/etc.) for the english field.

If you want to search both fields when querying, use `qf` (if using the (e)dismax query parser) to find documents matching in any of the fields.

Comment: Thanks for reply @matslindh
but the actual issue is
What if the file contains languages like
ex[japanese,english,korean]

Comment: I'm not aware of any built-in support for extracting blocks of text from a single field. Langid supports multiple languages, but discovers the language on a field basis. You might want to look into that to see if that's a correct assumption. Another option is to create your own update processor that extracts parts of the content that uses different areas of the encoding charset (picking out sections that uses the japanese / korean / latin parts of UTF-8, for instance) and then indexing each part to their own fields.